# Como migrar de c# 7.3 a c# 8.1

Tags: c#

alguien sabe donde se le indica a VS que migre la compilacion de c# al compilador c# 8.1 ?
por mas que actualizo mi VS2019, él sigue compilando con el c# 7.3 y no con el nuevo c# 8.1

gracias

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo a la experiencia del usuario en [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60247122/236345), desde 2019 les pareció una idea genial que edites manualmente la definición del proyecto.

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <LangVersion>[some version here]</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Y además, hay que revisar en los *build configurations* para quitar los casos especiales.
Finalmente, en LangVersion puedes usar el [identificador de versión](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version#c-language-version-reference) que corresponda a la opción que deseas (`8.0`?).